# PyInstaller - No module named 'codecs'

Tags: python, pyinstaller

My script literally looks like this (Python 3.5):

```
print("Hello world")
```

Building it with PyInstaller (version 3.5 I guess?) (`pyinstaller --onefile test.py` or even `pyinstaller test.py`) results in an error:

```
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "encodings\__init__.py", line 31, in (module)
ImportError: No module named 'codecs'.
```

I'm kinda new to Python, so I don't know what could be causing the problem nor do I know how to fix it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

What version of PyInstaller are you using? I think there might be a bug on older versions that could cause this error.

Try running "pip install --upgrade pyinstaller".

Comment: I just installed PyInstaller today and, accordingly, all upgrades were skipped.